# Opensource projects to learn asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have basic knowledge of Java and some experience with MVC pattern. I have followed asp.net mvc 3 tutorials and video's from The official Microsoft ASP.NET site and now want to move permanently to asp.net mvc 3.

Personally i think one of the best ways doing this is to contribute in an opensource project to learn from. But don't know how to achieve this.

For example how can i register for opensource project ? 
Does someone know an opensource project where i can leran from ? Specifically asp.net MVC.

Thnx,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this topic is more suited for programmers.stack-exchange. Anyhow you usually do not need to register for open source projects. You simply fork your version of the code add features and then send a patch/pull request to the owners. One of the better ways to start contributing to an opensource project is to go over the bug list and see what can you help fixing, this will teach you a lot about the codebase.

To find opensource projects you can scout this places:

- [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/)
- [Github](http://github.com)
- [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org)

Good luck :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can refer the free chapter release by :[Free — Scott Guthrie's (ScottGu) NerdDinner.com chapter!](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html) you can also find code related to this...

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried MVC 3 before, then I would start by working on examples from [here](http://rcm-uk.amazon.co.uk/e/cm?t=code0e-21&o=2&p=8&l=as1&asins=1430234040&ref=tf_til&fc1=000000&IS2=1&lt1=_blank&m=amazon&lc1=0000FF&bc1=000000&bg1=FFFFFF&f=ifr) This will give you enough insight. You may want to look at Orchard CMS - but I think that it'll be an overkill as it's quite complex.